# Visual studio cannot take snapshot of the memory because of the memory size when there is leak

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, memory-leaks, visual-studio-2017

I can see that there is a memory leak in my code (or most probably in one of the libraries that I am using). After a while that my code is running and I run my stress test, I can see that the used memory grows to 3GB easily and then it crashes some times.

I've stopped my stress test and tried to take a snapshot of the memory and see what is going on. But VS tells me that it cannot do it because of insufficient memory.

I have no other snapshots, and if I restart my app how can I see what is wrong? :)

What can I do to fix it?

Do I have any other way to find out if there are some blocked threats and who is blocking them, etc?

[image]

I've found [this post](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2621837/debug-managed-memory-for-10-gb-memory-dump-files) on Microsoft but it is for VS 2015 and people and it is just closed.

Comment: Red Gate do some nice tools for finding memory leaks.

Comment: JetBrains dotMemory.

Comment: Visual Studio tools also work. In fact, you don't even need to start profiling to see the memory usage window and take snapshots. Just go to `Debug > Windows > Show Diagnostic Tools` You'll be able to see the leak and take snapshots long before it gets out of hand

Comment: BTW a 3 GB leak is pretty huge. Are you trying to load a lot of data in memory? Are you processing large text files by splitting? Loading data using large buffers? What do the *performance counters* for the application show? You don't need a profiler to see that there are a lot of objects, or too many objects in olg GC generations

Comment: There's an open issue on the Developer Community: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/60975/debug-managed-memory-crashes-due-to-insufficient-m.html